# SQL Query to select names of courses that have prerequisite requirements and name of the prerequisite course

Tags: mysql, sql

**Course Table**

| course_id | course_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | s001 |
| 2 | s002 |
| 3 | s003 |
| 4 | s004 |

**Prerequisite Table**

| course_id | prerequisite_course_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

**My question is** to print both the Names of the course and the Prerequisite Course Name.
**Example:**

| course_name | prerequisite_course_name |
| --- | --- |
| s003 | s002 |
| s004 | s001 |

Comment: As this sounds like homework ... [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: If I add a row `(2,1)` into pre-requisites table then what should be the output?

Comment: @Akina if u add a row ```(2,1)``` then the output should be ```(s002, s001)```

Comment: ..  and no the row (s003, s001), no chained prerequisites, only immediate ones? well. If so then @KaziMohammadAliNur's answer must solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use inner join for that:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table course(course_id int, course_name varchar(10));
 insert into course values(1,   's001');
 insert into course values(2,   's002');
 insert into course values(3,   's003');
 insert into course values(4,   's004');
 
 create table Prerequisite(course_id int, prerequisite_course_id int);
 insert into Prerequisite values(3, 2);
 insert into Prerequisite values(4, 1);
```

Query:

```
 select c.course_name, pc.course_name
 from Course c inner join Prerequisite p 
               on c.course_id=p.course_id
              inner join Course pc
              on p.prerequisite_course_id=pc.course_id
```

Output:

| course_name | course_name |
| --- | --- |
| s004 | s001 |
| s003 | s002 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e53a390e4edfac8f3e52a320f49f5a3)*

Comment: I tried the same but having issues with primary keys.

Comment: What kind of issue you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

your data

```
drop 
  table if exists tmp_CourseTable;
create table tmp_CourseTable (
  course_id int NOT NULL, 
  course_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tmp_CourseTable(course_id, course_name) 
VALUES 
  (1, 's001'), 
  (2, 's002'), 
  (3, 's003'), 
  (4, 's004');
drop 
  table if exists tmp_PrerequisiteTable;
create table tmp_PrerequisiteTable (
  course_id INTEGER NOT NULL , 
  prerequisite_course_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tmp_PrerequisiteTable(
  course_id, prerequisite_course_id
) 
VALUES 
  (3, 2), 
  (4, 1);
```

you should join **Prerequisite** Table with **Course** Table **twice**

```
select 
  a.course_name, 
  b.course_name 
from 
  tmp_PrerequisiteTable p 
  join tmp_CourseTable a on p.course_id = a.course_id 
  join tmp_CourseTable b on p.course_id = b.course_id
```

Comment: Your query will fail on your sample data (temporary table cannot be reused). While fixing the syntax your query gives incorrect output. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6dbd44f44f5c899b7f5d74bcf82cb07c